# Error while installing GDAL

Tags: python, pip, gdal

I'm trying to install GDAL through pip. But I'm getting this error:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3089:27: fatal error: cpl_vsi_error.h: No such     file or directory
 #include "cpl_vsi_error.h"
                           ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip install GDAL
```

Can anyone tell me how to install it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294127/python-gdal-2-1-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check that you installed GDAL using this command

```
gdal-config --version
```

Then run this commands:

```
pip download="some_path" GDAL
cd some_path
tar -xvzf GDAL-<version>.tar.gz
cd GDAL-<version>
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: for anyone else stuck, depending on how you installed GDAL you might have a different location for the missing header file. i installed via kyngchaos and for me the correct path was:

`--include-dirs=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers/`

Comment: `pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')`

Comment: `pip3 download "$HOME/Downloads/" GDAL` 
`ERROR: Directory '/home/leonardo/Downloads/' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`

Comment: I was instructed to download the "core" and the "python bindings" binaries to my computer. Are these all I need to download? having done so, the command `gdal-config --version ` produces an error saying it is not recognized as a command as per my question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667487/gdalinfo-not-recognized-after-installing-and-setting-path-variables)

Answer (score 24):

```
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')
```

This is a copy-paste of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630474/error-while-installing-gdal#comment70408136_38630941) by nicerobot, that at this time received more up votes than all currently posted answers combined.

As far as I can tell, it asks pip to install the pip package of the same version as the installed gdal system package.

Answer (score 17):

On my MacBook, the update/fresh install of GDAL using [this](https://www.karambelkar.info/2016/10/gdal-2-on-mac-with-homebrew/) approach with homebrew worked out fine. The problem on my Mac was that I apparently had an old GDAL version installed and wasn't able to update with `brew upgrade gdal` because of the above error message.

**Solution in short:**

```
brew unlink gdal
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac && brew tap --repair
brew install jasper netcdf # gdal dependencies
brew install gdal2 --with-armadillo --with-complete --with-libkml --with-unsupported
brew link --force gdal2
```

**Verification:**

```
$> gdal-config --version
2.1.3
$> gdal-config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.1.3_3/lib -lgdal
$> gdal-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.1.3_3/include
```

Comment: Had to do a mix of some of the above answers but got this to work on my Mac running el capitan! Before installing with felice's brew answer I had to run `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/
` After the brew installs I had to run: `pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')`

Comment: You need to do the above "Solution in short" first, then do the "verification" and lastly do  `pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')` by imapotoatoe123.

Comment: Worked with fix from @imapotatoe123

Comment: Everytime I read `awk -F` here, it reads in my mind as awkward as F*. :D

Answer (score 4):

I had to include the header files as well to successfully install gdal:

```
sudo pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}') --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal"
```

Note: Using Python 3 and gdal was already installed on centOS

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **activate the environment** where you want gdal to be installed. Then simply try command:

```
[conda install -c conda-forge gdal]
```

Refer to this [link](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/how-to-install-gdal-with-anaconda/).
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [@nicerobot comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630474/error-while-installing-gdal#comment70408136_38630941), and adding a command to make it work in case you run into

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GDAL

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')
```