# Unable to install gdal in python 3.6.1 in macos Sierra

Tags: python, macos, gdal

I was trying to install gdal in python 3.6.1, but getting the following error. How to overcome this?

```
bibinwilson ~ $ pip3 install gdal
```

> ```
> Collecting gdal   Downloading GDAL-2.2.1.tar.gz (475kB)
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 397kB/s 
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> running egg_info
> creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
> writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
> writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
> warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 131, in fetch_config
>     p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
> line 707, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
>   line 1326, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 179, in get_gdal_config
>     return fetch_config(option, gdal_config = self.gdal_config)
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 135, in fetch_config
>     raise gdal_config_error(e)
> __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 131, in fetch_config
>     p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
> line 707, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
> line 1326, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 339, in <module>
>     **extra )
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py",
> line 148, in setup
>     dist.run_commands()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py",
> line 955, in run_commands
>     self.run_command(cmd)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py",
> line 974, in run_command
>     cmd_obj.run()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
> line 279, in run
>     self.find_sources()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
> line 306, in find_sources
>     mm.run()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
> line 533, in run
>     self.add_defaults()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
> line 562, in add_defaults
>     sdist.add_defaults(self)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py",
> line 36, in add_defaults
>     self._add_defaults_ext()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py",
> line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
>     build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 299, in get_finalized_command
>     cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 107, in ensure_finalized
>     self.finalize_options()
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 214, in finalize_options
>     self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 188, in get_gdal_config
>     return fetch_config(option)
>   File "/private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/setup.py",
> line 135, in fetch_config
>     raise gdal_config_error(e)
> __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> /private/var/folders/43/7yqv__4j5776m508kggs_dxm0000gn/T/pip-build-naebgem9/gdal/
> ```

Answer (score 15):

I had this error and installing GDAL through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) fixed this for me. Installing the the binaries for GDAL didn't correct the error but once I installed through brew it was resolved.

```
brew install gdal
```

seems like the same issue as here: [Python GDAL: pip install --no-install GDAL fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888005/python-gdal-pip-install-no-install-gdal-fails)

If you've already installed the binaries (like I had) then this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44051123/3969685

Comment: That was easy! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

This simple procedure seemed to work for me on MAC sierra, python 3.6, GDAL 2.2.3

1) Install GDAL framework using dmg installer for MAC [GDAL MAC 
Frameworks]: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks

2) Add gdal-config folder to your path and get your version:

`$ export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Programs:$PATH`

`$ gdal-config --version`

3) Use pip to install the version reported by `gdal-config --version`:

`$ pip install gdal==2.2.3`

Step 1 Seems to set up the python site-packages under its install framework folders and I think you could copy them to your python site-packages. But better to use pip install.

Comment: Life saving ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This simple procedure seemed to work for me on MAC

1. Install GDAL framework using Brew
   > brew install gdal
2. gdal-config --version

> gdal-config --version
>
> > 2.4.4
> > 3. GDAL Python binding
> > pip3 install gdal==2.4.4

Note the GDAL version of the end of the command, it must be the same as the obtained in the step above using gdal-config. To avoid conflicts or any further issues, it’s important to install and use the exact versions that any component will require.