# When trying to install GDAL with pip to a macOS I keep getting an error about a file not found, shouldn't the installer have all of the files?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, installation, pip, gdal

When I try using pip install to get GDAL I run into an error about a file not found. I went to the location and there is definitely no folder there but shouldn't the installer install the folder it needs first?

```
Collecting GDAL
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/b0/a2ecb10a68a319910c4681f452c83843b99c4ef6231d33a8e55b0104a50c/GDAL-2.4.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 151, in fetch_config
    p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config': '../../apps/gdal-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 237, in get_gdal_config
    return fetch_config(option, gdal_config=self.gdal_config)
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 154, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error(e)
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config': '../../apps/gdal-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 151, in fetch_config
    p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 430, in <module>
    setup(**setup_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
```

.................................

```
  File "/private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/setup.py", line 154, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error(e)
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/js/c2_gdy711m7933z9bxcv2q5h0000gn/T/pip-install-jv2fugnm/GDAL/
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Unable to install gdal in python 3.6.1 in macos Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898463/unable-to-install-gdal-in-python-3-6-1-in-macos-sierra)