# How to make pip see packages installed with homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I was having trouble installing a Python package with pip. `pip install gdal` failed so instead I tried installing with homebrew as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898463/unable-to-install-gdal-in-python-3-6-1-in-macos-sierra), running `brew install gdal`. This worked, but pip doesn't know the package exists, so it tries to install it when installing a package that depends on it. I want pip to be able to use packages installed by brew. My computer runs MacOS 10.14 and I'm using Python 3 with pip 19.0.3 and Homebrew 2.0.2

Comment: try this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `brew install gdal` doesn't install a python package — it installs GDAL library. After that you still have to install Python wrapper by running `pip install gdal`.

Comment: Oh I see. But when i run `pip install gdal`, I get a fatal error saying `#include <stdexcept>` was not found in `extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp`.