# How to install GDAL in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I've got Ubuntu 17.04 version installed and I want to install GDAL. I have tried several ways to install it, but always I've got an error. I have installed Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 but I want to do the install for Python 2.7

I have tried to do the installation following these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev export
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal export
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal pip install GDAL
```

And I've got this error:

```
Collecting GDAL
  Using cached GDAL-2.2.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Running setup.py install for GDAL ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-iebgcn_u/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x3vhb2t4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gnm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    Fixing build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -lgdal -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdalconst_wrap.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdalconst_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -lgdal -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_gdalconst.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    building 'osgeo._osr' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/osr_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/osr_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:3339:13: warning: ‘void GDALPythonFreeCStr(void*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static void GDALPythonFreeCStr(void* ptr, int bToFree)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:3309:14: warning: ‘char* GDALPythonObjectToCStr(PyObject*, int*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static char* GDALPythonObjectToCStr(PyObject* pyObject, int* pbToFree)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/osr_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -lgdal -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_osr.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/ogr_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/ogr_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -lgdal -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_ogr.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gnm_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:3321:13: warning: ‘void GDALPythonFreeCStr(void*, int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static void GDALPythonFreeCStr(void* ptr, int bToFree)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:3291:14: warning: ‘char* GDALPythonObjectToCStr(PyObject*, int*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static char* GDALPythonObjectToCStr(PyObject* pyObject, int* pbToFree)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gnm_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -lgdal -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_gnm.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    running install_lib
    copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gdal.py': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-iebgcn_u/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x3vhb2t4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-iebgcn_u/GDAL/
```

If I execute the last command withs sudo: sudo pip install GDAL. I've got this another error ...

```
The directory '/home/josecarlos/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory '/home/josecarlos/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Collecting GDAL   Downloading GDAL-2.2.3.tar.gz (475kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 1.3MB/s  Installing collected packages: GDAL   Running setup.py install for GDAL ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0rp6w4f8/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /tmp/pip-w7crvfsd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gnm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    Fixing build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-sXpGnM/python3.6-3.6.3=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3168:10: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
     #include "cpl_port.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ---------------------------------------- Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0rp6w4f8/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /tmp/pip-w7crvfsd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0rp6w4f8/GDAL/
```

How can I install GDAL in Ubuntu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613466/8150371

Comment: What's wrong with the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/python-gdal)?

Comment: The installation works!!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you'll have more choices if you download the package and read the readme.txt.
[downloadpage](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource)

im not that confident with all those command parameters on my own.

hope it helps^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the Ubuntu version more than Python. I didn't find much information about ubuntu 17, so you should try what is available for the older and more stable versions.

Answer (score -1):

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613466/12952347) seems to help her, too. According to comments it also worked on Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04:

**If you don't have any gdal previous version installed**

Open your terminal and type

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```

**If you have a previous version installed**

Open your terminal and type

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```