# Convert EPSG:900913 to EPSG:3857 with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I have a GeoTIFF file that appears to be EPSG:900913 and I need to convert it to a kmz file. I am trying to convert the EPSG:900913 to the correct EPSG:3857 using GDAL but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 900913 not found in EPSG support files.
Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?
```

**Command Code**

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3857 some.tif some_corrected.tif
gdal2tiles.py some_corrected.tif
```

I am using GDAL v1.11.3

Comment: I solved this issue by using the following method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613466/6932839

Comment: Voting to close because it was resolved on another SO post.